# Jq doesn't highlight Docker inspect output

Tags: json, docker, cmd, jq, conemu

When executing `docker-machine inspect` command, instead of the expected highlighted version of JSON piped into jq:

[image]

I'm seeing the following plain output (in cmd or ConEmu):

[image]

Not sure what needs to be done to enable proper json highlighting.

This happens on Windows 10 machine on which jq ver. 1.5 was installed via Chocolatey:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it a question to jq authors? Your tool have to output ANSI sequences to get colors in the console.

Comment: Have you tried using the -C command-line option?

Comment: @Maximus: Thanks, I thought they would be active here, but placed a post on jq github issues list just now.  @peak: Updated the question: the output is for `docker-machine inspect` command, not sure it where this option would fit, at least I'm getting `flag provided not defined: -C` error when supplying it with  `docker-machine inspect -C swarm-1`

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon try adding the `-C` option to jq e.g.  `jq -C .`   See [invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I guess ConEmu is not considered a terminal in this case as the jq documentation you pointed me to says: `By default, jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is an idiosyncrasy of jq Windows implementation, forcing the color output with -C option, as hinted by several commenters above, resolved the issue for me:

[image]